# How to limit Angular Material multiple select items to N items?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

In using https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection

How to limit the number of items selected to N number? Where N is 3 or 4 or 5.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the `selectionChange` output event on the `mat-select` component, point it to your component function: `(selectionChange)="changed()"`.

snippet:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" (selectionChange)="changed()" multiple>
```

In your component create a global variable named `mySelections`. This will store your selections :) It will hold an array of strings.

It looks like this:

```
mySelections: string[];

changed() {
  if (this.toppings.value.length < 3) {
    this.mySelections = this.toppings.value;
  } else {
    this.toppings.setValue(this.mySelections);
  }
}
```

Change the number 3 to N and presto, you're done.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this using the disabled property on the mat-option like so:

```
<mat-select formControlName="myCtrl" multiple>
            <mat-option [disabled]="formGroup.get('myCtrl').value?.length > 2 && !formGroup.get('myCtrl').value?.includes(o)"
                        *ngFor="let o of itemList"
                        [value]="o">{{o.name}}
            </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: @iambatman if you've limited it to 3 and you've checked 3 then the those three should still be enabled which means if you uncheck 1 of the three all the checkboxes will be enabled again

Answer (score 6):

The best solution is based on only if you disable only unselected options. Otherwise it is meaningless because after you disable all options, then how is that possible to unselect any of options?

in HTML component:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Category" [formControl]="categories" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let cat of categoryArr" [value]="cat.id"
      [disabled]="isOptionDisabled(cat.id)">
      {{cat.title}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

in controller:

```
isOptionDisabled(opt: any): boolean {
  return this.categories.value.length >= 3 && !this.categories.value.find(el => el == opt)
}
```

Now: Only already selected options are enable to do something, other options are disabled, as follows:

[image: Only already selected options are enable to do something, other options are disabled]

User can uncheck any of checked options so that user have chance to be able to do check/uncheck on the form field.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" (selectionChange)="selectionChanged(event)" multiple>
```

...

```
selectionChanged({ value }: MatSelectChange) {
  if (value.length >= 3) {
    this.formGroup.patchValue({
        toppings: value.slice(0, 3)
    });
  }
}
```